# What is the dual vector space of $\mathbb{C}\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Given that the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ are considered to be canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$, I am wondering if the dual space of $\mathbb{C}$ is the same es that of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the vector space of linear functionals. I never heard about dual space of $\mathbb{C}$ until today, so I couldnt find much information in the litterature.
Also:

- How is the dual of $\mathbb{C}$ defined, what is a dual basis of $\mathbb{C}$ ?
- What is the field $K$ in which the linear functionals get their values ($\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) ?

Many thanks.

Comment: The dual of any vector space $V$ over a field $K$ is the space of linear functionals $f:V\to K$.

Comment: For a finite dimensional vector space $\mathbb{F}^n$ (possibly barring some characteristic 2 issues - I'm a bit cloudy on it right now and fairly distraught, so I'm not sure about this), the dual space is $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why should characteristic $2$ be special here? It isn't.

Comment: The Question has to tell Readers whether $\mathbb C$ is being considered a vector space over the field $\mathbb R$ or over the field $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @egreg I didn't think it was but I was having a particularly bad day today so I couldn't think well haha.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your questions depends upon your answer to this question: do you see $\mathbb C$ as a real vector space or as a complex vector space?

Since you mention $\mathbb{R}^2$, I'll assume that you see it as a real vector space. In that case:

- A basis of $\mathbb{C}^*$ is $\{\alpha,\beta\}$, with $\alpha(z)=\operatorname{Re}z$ and $\beta(z)=\operatorname{Im}z$.
- The functionals get their values in $\mathbb R$.

On the other hand, if you see $\mathbb C$ as a complex vector space, then you can take *any* map $\alpha\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ of the type $\alpha(z)=az$ (as long as $a\neq0$) and $\{\alpha\}$ will be a basis of $\mathbb{C}^*$. For instance, you can take $\alpha=\operatorname{Id}$ (which corresponds to choosing $a=1$).

Comment: Many thanks. So in that case is then obvious that $\alpha (1)=1, \alpha (i)=0$ and $\beta (1)=0, \beta (i)=1.$ How about if one considered $\mathbb{C}$ as a complex vector space ?

Comment: @user249018 Indeed. Of course, a shorter answer to the first question would have been $\{\operatorname{Re},\operatorname{Im}\}$.

Comment: Since {1} is the only basis vector of $\mathbb{C}$ considered as a complex vector space, one would expect a single dual basis vector, say $\theta$. I am wondering if $\theta (1)=1$ or $0$ ?

Comment: @user249018 Acutaly, for every $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $\{z\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb C$, if we see it as a complex vector space. But, yes, then $\mathbb{C}^*$ will be $1$-dimensional. Please see the paragraph that I've added.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by {z} is a basis of $\mathbb {C}$ ? You can not have for each $z\in \mathbb {C} \setminus {0}$ a new basis vector. Did you mean something else ?

Comment: @user249018 No. What I wrote is what I meant: for each $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $\{z\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb C$, if we see it as a complex vector space. Why do you ask? Do you know some non-zero complex number $z$ such that $\{z\}$ is **not** a basis of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Ok,thanks. It is clear that in $\mathbb {R}$ you can take any non zero element to be a basis of $\mathbb {R}$. One usually takes ${1}$ though. So then it ist not different in $\mathbb {C}$.